# Why can't I change my location in Google Wallet?

Tags: google-wallet

I recently bought a Google Play gift card (in SGD). When I tried redeeming it, an error was shown,"cannot be redeemed in your country"

Then I went on to change my location in the settings.

[image]

It thus gave me another error. I have 0.00 money in my wallet. I don't understand why I have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

At present, the Google Wallet app is only supported in a few countries.  The only form of Google Wallet available in other countries is the desktop version.

This is stated in Google's  [FAQ](http://www.google.co.uk/wallet/faq.html) .

[image: Screenshot of Google FAQ]

You won't be able to change your country from within the Android app.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the desktop version :)

Answer (score -1):

Well, I have been looking over the [Google FAQ about Google wallet](http://www.google.com/wallet/faq.html#tab=faq-gift).There's a category gift card under which question is asked

> Q. Why don’t I get balance automatically for all gift cards I add to Wallet?

and according to them there are **"Certain types of gift cards don't support automatic balance updates. For these gift cards, you can type in the original balance and update it manually from within the app."** So I am going to advise you the same.

Comment: No, I cannot even add the gift card to my wallet.

Comment: How does this answer the question at all?